# Can't make overflow-x work in a full width flexbox column

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a 2 column layout with flexbox. One is fixed width on the side and the other one (main column) fills the remaining space.

It was working until I put some contents wider than the screen with a `overflow-x: scroll` parent. Now this wide content is not limited by its scroller parent.

Here is the sample:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container .col-main {
  background: gold;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.container .col-side {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  flex: 0 0 15em;
}

.slider-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.slider-container .slider {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, darkseagreen, darkseagreen 10px, dimgray 10px, dimgray 20px);
  width: 150em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-main">

    <div class=slider-container>
      <div class="slider">
        Foo
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-side">
    Side
  </div>
</div>
```

It should be rendered like this:
[image]

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to `.col-main`.

Answer (score 19):

Try adding `min-width: 0;` to the flex item.

```
.container .col-main {
  ...
  min-width: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buahdeco/)**

[4.5. Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)

> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of the `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1. [CSS21]

Answer (score 7):

You can add `width: 0` to the container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .col-main {
  background: gold;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  width: 0;
}

.container .col-side {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  flex: 0 0 15em;
}

.slider-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.slider-container .slider {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, darkseagreen, darkseagreen 10px, dimgray 10px, dimgray 20px);
  width: 150em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-main">

    <div class=slider-container>
      <div class="slider">
        Foo
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-side">
    Side
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So that works... width: 0, ok CSS I'm all for flex, but absolute WTF here